# How to filter Gridview columns on the basis of column type

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to filter Gridview columns on the basis of **column type(i.e. Bound field , template field etc...)**

Suppose i have a gridview with following code

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        emptydatatext="No data available." 
        runat="server">

        <columns>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" headertext="Postal Code"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="Country" headertext="Country"/>

      <asp:templatefield headertext="Author Name">
        <itemtemplate>
          <asp:label id="FirstNameLabel"
            Text= '<%# Eval("au_fname") %>'
            runat="server"/> 
          <asp:label id="LastNameLabel"
            Text= '<%# Eval("au_lname") %>'
            runat="server"/>
        </itemtemplate>
      </asp:templatefield>

      <asp:hyperlinkfield text="Details..."
        navigateurl="~\details.aspx"            
        headertext="Order Details"
        target="_blank" />
        </columns>

      </asp:gridview>
```

Now i want to run through all the boundfields only (so last 2 columns should be filtered out).

I know it can be done by going through all the columns of a gridview and checking column type(with `grdView.Columns[ct].GetType().Name;`) but in my actual scenario it may be having 25 - 30 columns so **dnt want to run through all columns but want to filter out only boundfileds first and then run through them**

I dont want run a loop through all the available columns ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, to filter columns, you have to look at each of them to check whether the column satisfies your condition. So you have to loop over all of them in any case, it can be explicit, or implicit, but it is there.

You can use Linq for something like that,

```
var filtered = CustomerGridView.Columns.Where( 
    column => column.GetType().Name == "Some column type" );
```

It returns an IEnumerable (actually, a lazy generator behind the scenes), which only gets evaluated when you actually iterate over it.

Comment: ya but if it is implicit it will be optimized .. otherwise why we use ds.clone and ds.copy and all of those function ... same way when we want filter our something in particular column we will use ds.filter not going to scan all the rows in dataset .. so want to check if any implicit way

Comment: Mainly ds.clone and ds.copy have to do with hiding implementation of common operations. As there is no such implementation for filtering columns, well, you can roll out your own, or use Linq. See my answer.

Comment: yeah i know ... i need to loop through all the columns as i have show in my question ...